# How do you rotate on a complex coordinate plane?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rotations

For a Precalculus assignment, I am supposed to write two expressions that describe what happens when you rotate a robot 90 degrees left or right on a [complex coordinate plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6JWu.png). The magnitude equals one. If the robot is facing south, the direction, d, is -i. If the robot is facing north, d = i. If the robot is facing east, d = 1. If the robot is facing west, d = -1. This is what I have come up with so far: [Table of Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc7gt.png)

For left turns, I have been thinking about the ways to turn -1 into -i, 1 into i, i into -1 and -i into 1. I know that the square root of negative one is i and that i^2 is -1. I can use this knowledge to turn left for each of the above values, but I can't think of a single expression to write for d that would give me d - 90 degrees for each situation. For example, to turn left from -1 to -i, I could take the negative square root of -1 to equal -i, but to turn i into -1, I have to square i. I don't want anyone to do my homework for me, but could anyone give me a hint to write these expressions? Am I on the right track, or should I think about the problem differently?

Thanks

PS: I'm still learning how to use this site. If I'm not supposed to ask homework questions on here, let me know and I will stop.

Comment: Have you learned the arithmetic of complex numbers? In particular how to multiply two complex numbers and how to divide two complex numbers? For example, can you compute $\frac{-1}{i}$? If so, then I would suggest focussing on arithmetic, and trying to find geometric patterns in the formulas of arithmetic (and forgetting about things like "the negative square root of $-1$").

Comment: Do you know about the polar form for complex numbers? Homework problems are OK as long as they're not requests for a solution without any work or thought shown.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Yes, I just finished learning how to multiply, divide, add, and subtract complex numbers.

Comment: @RandyMarsh I know how to convert complex numbers to polar form.

Comment: Hint: if $z=r_1(\cos\varphi +\sin\varphi)$ and $w=r_2(\cos\theta +\sin\theta)$, look at $zw$ in its polar form. If you want to rotate $z$ for 90 degrees, how should $w$ look like?

Comment: @RandyMarsh Marsh Is w supposed to be the opposite of z?

Comment: @RandyMarsh: you are missing $i$.

Comment: @RachelJ: no, $z$ and $w$ are arbitrary complex numbers. The hint is to help you figure out what the geometric interpretation of complex multiplication is. It may help to restrict yourself to the case $r_1 = r_2 = 1$ (which is all you are asking about in your question in any case).

Comment: Yes, thank you @NickD.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help! I think I figured it out! For left turns, the expression is d times i. For right turns, the expression is d times -i.